# Does DS OVERLAY support VARCHAR sub-fields?

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

**Here's the source code**

```
     Dcl-S dataString VarChar(1048576:4) Inz;
     Dcl-DS Ds_ErrMsg Qualified;
       ErrMsg      VarChar(249);  //22+1+21+1+200 = 245
                                  //extra 4 bytes for VarChar? What sub-fields exactly?
         date_iso    VarChar(22)  Inz('Error Date: ')
                                  Overlay(ErrMsg);
         *n          Char(1)      Inz(x'25') Overlay(ErrMsg:*Next);
         id          VarChar(21)  Inz('Error ID. . . . : ')
                                  Overlay(ErrMsg:*Next);
         *n          Char(1)      Inz(x'25') Overlay(ErrMsg:*Next);
         message     VarChar(200) Inz('Error. . . . : ')
                                  Overlay(ErrMsg:*Next);
     End-Ds;

     Ds_ErrMsg.date_iso += %Char(%Date);
     Ds_ErrMsg.id       += '100';
     Ds_ErrMsg.message  += 'No Response Received. ' +
                           'Call to test API ended in error.';

     dataString = Ds_ErrMsg.ErrMsg;

     *InLR = *On;
```

**Below is the output**

[image]

**Expected Output**

```
Error Date: 2023-11-15
Error ID. : 100
Error . . : No Response Received. Call to test API ended in error.
```

Also, the DS actually has 4 VARCHAR sub-fields, When declared size is 245, I get the following error during compile.

```
*RNF7303 30        001000  Subfield MESSAGE defined with keyword OVERLAY is too big;specification ignored.
```

Which makes sense, that I'd need to add Variable part of VARCHAR, so 2 bytes for each variable sub-field (2 bytes * 4 fields = 8 bytes), hence the new size should be 245+8 = 253 bytes i.e. `VarChar(253)`, and the program also compiles when given the size of `VarChar(249)`. Not sure how that worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 4 varchar fields but 3 of them overlay the other one so the size in bytes is 245 + 6 = 251 which is also the size of `errmsg` (249 + 2 = 251)

Btw the 2 bytes of `date_iso` overlay the 2 bytes of `errmsg`, so when you set `Ds_ErrMsg.date_iso += %Char(%Date);` you set the length of `errmsg` too.
And when you use `errmsg`, it show data only for the length of `date_iso`

But `DS_ERRMSG` is defined as you coded :

```
EVAL ds_errmsg:c
DS_ERRMSG:C =                                                          
          ....5...10...15...20...25...30...35...40...45...50...55...60 
     1   ' █Error Date: 2023-12-04█ █Error ID. . . . : 100█ áError. . '
    61   '. . : No Response Received. Call to test API ended in error.'
   121   '                                                            '
   181   '                                                            '
   241   '           '
```

I think concatenation is a better tool for doing what you want to do. See [%concat](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.5?topic=functions-concat-concatenate-separator)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @nfgl. %CONCAT shall be indeed helpful here.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a good idea to overlay varying length subfields over other varying length subfields. The big ErrMsg string has the 2-byte unsigned integers that hold the length for the overlaying subfields, and those 2 bytes would appear as garbage data in your ErrMsg string.

I agree that concatenation is a much better way to build up your message.

You probably don't even need your ErrMsg subfield. You can just set the value of dataString directly by concatenating the other three subfields.

Comment: You're right, I was wondering why I'm getting 'á' before the 'Error'. That explains it. Thank you for the explanation @Barbara.